# How to add a range of values in a Json and return the objects that are in that range

Tags: java, spring, api, controller

I am trying to create a method in my Controller class to return a list of Locations

I want to give it a range of latitudes and longitudes and return locations that fall in that list.

Currently the Get methon in my controller class looks like

```
@GetMapping public ResponseEntity<List<Location>> searchLocations(
    @RequestParam(required = false) Location.LocationType type,
    @RequestParam Double lat1, @RequestParam Double lng1, 
    @RequestParam Double lat2, @RequestParam Double lng2,
    @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer limit) {
    
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, limit);
    List<Location> locations = locationRepository.findByLatBetweenAndLngBetweenAndTypeOrderByTypeDesc(
        Math.min(lat1, lat2), Math.max(lat1, lat2), Math.min(lng1, lng2), Math.max(lng1, lng2), type, pageable);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(locations); }
```

and the data I would pass in is

```
{
"lat1": 46.6,
"lng1": 46.6, 
"lat2": 48.8, 
"lng2": 48.8,
"type": "premium",
"limit": 3
}
```

I would like to pass in a Json that looks like

```
"p1": 46.6, 15.4
"p2": 48.8, 17.5
"type": "premium"
"limit": 3
```

So the p1 and p2 are points and it returns the locations within those points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `@RequestBody` for passing a structure, you are currently processing URL parameters.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Location>> searchLocations(
    @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto
) {
    . . . .
```

In JSON you can't return values in that way.

You have to do something like this:

```
{
  "p1": {
     "lat": 46.6,
     "lng": 15.4
   },
   "p2": {
     "lat": 48.8,
     "lng": 17.5
    },
    "type": "premium",
    "limit": 3
}
```

Or an array of values (which IMHO looks awful):

```
{
  "p1": [ 46.6, 15.4 ],
  "p2": [ 48.8, 17.5 ],
  "type": "premium",
  "limit": 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to change/refactor my controller @GetMapping request at all?

Comment: @RequestParam means each value is in the URL: ?lat1=46.6&lng1=46.6&lat2=48.8&lng2=48.8&... . If you want to pass a structure look at `@RequestBody`